# How to extract data from the BLE Peripheral characteristic write callback in Swift?

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an iOS App in Swift language. The App acts as a BLE peripheral with 4 custom writable GATT characteristics. Whenever any of the characteristics is written by the client a call back is triggered by iOS through the following function:

```
func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest`])
```

.I want to know how to extract the characteristic data from the above callback function. Can anyone help me understand by sharing a sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 4

```
func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWriteRequests requests: [CBATTRequest])
{
    for request in requests
    {
        if request.characteristic.UUID.isEqual(characteristic.UUID) 
        {
            // Set the request's value
            // to the correspondent characteristic
            characteristic.value = request.value
        }
  }
    peripheralManager.respondToRequest(requests[0], withResult: .Success)
}
```

may be it will work for you

[go through  that link for more about BLE](https://medium.com/@shu223/core-bluetooth-snippets-with-swift-9be8524600b2)